# get(..., inherits=TRUE) doesn't find variable in enclosing scope

Tags: r

The following works if `y` is defined in the global REPL scope but otherwise says `y` is not found:

```
f = function() {
    print(get('y', inherits=TRUE))
}
g = function() {
    y = 3
    f()
}
```

I thought that `inherits=TRUE` (which is the default) should inspect the call stack, including the enclosing scope.

How can I get this to work? The context is that a library I'm using uses get() when parsing a formula, and what works interactively fails when I try and do it programmatically inside a function I've written.

Comment: Looks like you want to use `dynGet` instead of `get`.

Comment: See also: [Function environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `envir = parent.frame()` to `get`:

```r
f = function() {
    print(get('y', inherits=TRUE, envir = parent.frame()))
}

g = function() {
    y = 3
    f()
}

g()
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Adding `envir = parent.frame()` will work only for one level back, but not for more: `f = function() {print(get('y', inherits=TRUE, envir = parent.frame()))}; g = function() {f()}; h = function() {y = 3; g()}; h()` while `dynGet` will still work: `f = function() {print(dynGet('y'))}; g = function() {f()}; h = function() {y = 3; g()}; h()`. But `dynGet` is *somewhat experimental* and *Use with caution*.

Comment: @GKi exactly. `parent.frame()` can actually look back a specified number of generations - you can do `parent.frame(2)` etc. Normally that's sufficient control for scoping within a package - but of course it's possible to come up with situations where a different method is more appropriate.